# Javascript if and else runs simultaneously

Tags: javascript, html

I want a link to select by onclick, when the link is clicked so selected, the background should change. When I click the selected link again then the background should be transparent again.

My Script:

```
<div style="background: transparent;" onclick="click()" id="0">
```

HTML:

Click

```
function click() {
  var click = document.getElementById("0");
  if(click.style.background == "transparent") {
    click.style.background = "red";
  }
  else {
    click.style.background = "transparent";
  }
}
```

Comment: An id of `0` is not valid HTML

Comment: You also have an extra `)` on line 7

Comment: but that does not matter for Js

Comment: how are you establishing that the if and else runs simultaneously and how are you attaching this as an event handler and to what?

Comment: click.style.background-color = "red"

Comment: @LeoFarmer `background` should work fine but it you want to use `background-color`, the correct property name is `backgroundColor`

Comment: its actually click.style.backgroundColor, otherwise you are minusing color from background

Comment: @JohnConde Hate to burst your bubble but HTML5 allows `0` as a valid ID attribute value - http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7X8L7/1/

Comment: One problem I see is that initially, the `background` property is neither `transparent` or `red`. In Chrome at least, it appears to be a blank string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you simply want a toggle. Functional code as follows.

2 important notes:

- ID must not be zero (or it breaks): I replaced it by 10;
- don't use click() as it's a reserved name: I replaced it by toggle().

Not much change to your code apart from the above.
Cheers.

Update to handle multiple divs: I now pass the object:

```
<html>
        <body>
            <div style="background: red;" onclick="toggle(this)" id="10">
                    CLICK ON 10 TO TOGGLE MY BACKGROUND COLOR
            </div>
            <div style="background: red;" onclick="toggle(this)" id="20">
                    CLICK ON 20 TO TOGGLE MY BACKGROUND COLOR
            </div>
            <script>
                function toggle(o) {
                  if(o.style.background == "transparent") {
                    o.style.background = "red";
                    alert("red on "+o.id);
                  }
                  else {
                    o.style.background = "transparent";
                    alert("transparent on "+o.id);
                  }
                }
            </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what happend when i have two div tags ore even more

Comment: You can pass this as the argument to the function, then test what div is that. I edit my answer to reflect this @Selfproblemmade

Comment: Weird: your fiddle don't found toggle() function (I had a look in the inspector).Simply copy/paste my code in a file toggle.html and you see it working (I work on safari). @Selfproblemmade I did a mod to your fiddle to make it work here http://jsfiddle.net/stephanedeluca/Pt79C/3/

Comment: I tried to understand why your initial fiddle didn't work with no success. I simply put the js into a script tag and voila. (I'm interested to understand why the fiddle wasn't working if you find an explanation.@Selfproblemmade You may want to accept my answer then :-)

Answer (score 1):

Two things here, don't call the function click, and use the backgroundColor property, not background as background is a compound property expecting more values than just the color, so comparing it to just a color (i.e. = 'transparent") may not work

so

HTML:

```
<div style="background-color: transparent;" onclick="notclick()" id="0">
```

Javascript

```
function notclick() {
  var click = document.getElementById("0");
  if(click.style.backgroundColor == "transparent") {
    click.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
  else {
    click.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

to handle mutliple div

every div that you want the behaviour, should be like this (i.e. with the onclick(this))

```
<div style="background-color: transparent;" onclick="notclick(this)" id="0">
<div style="background-color: transparent;" onclick="notclick(this)" id="1">
<div style="background-color: transparent;" onclick="notclick(this)" id="2">
```

and the javascript should be

```
function notclick(ele) {

  if(ele.style.backgroundColor == "transparent") {
    ele.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
  else {
    ele.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
  }
}
```

or better still

```
function notclick(ele) {     
  ele.style.backgroundColor = (ele.style.backgroundColor == "transparent" ? "red" :"transparent");
  }
```

Comment: how to do background color transparent in ie?

Comment: not sure what you are seeing, as I just testing it from 7 -11 (emulated) and all worked fine?

Comment: what happend when i have two div tags ore even more

Comment: well, I wouldn't do it the way you are doing it then if you have multiple divs and you want the behavior to all be independent, after all using document.getElementById("0") is pretty specific to one element, but that would be a whole different scenario to this question - It seems to me that you may have a bigger picture than this question, if so, enlighten us, we would love to help

Comment: and you want that other div (the id of 1) to have the same behavior?

Comment: jeah, i have lot of links in my menu

Comment: well, as per @Stéphane de Luca pass in 'this', and give it a parameter for the function, although his code doesn't work, so I'll add my version to the bottom of my answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the method name click, inside the onclick handler it refers to the internal click method - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7X8L7/2/) - here `click` is a native method, not our method

Rename it and it should be fine - you need to use `backgroundColor`

```
<button onclick="testme()">Test</button>
```

then

```
function testme() {
    var click = document.getElementById("0");
    if (click.style.background == "red") {
        click.style.background = "transparent";
    } else {
        click.style.background = "red";
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7X8L7/)

Comment: no, this isnt that what i want, see here http://jsfiddle.net/7X8L7/3/, but when i clicked this at first time there is no reaction.

Comment: @Selfproblemmade you wanted to toggle the background color isn't it - that functionality seems to be working in the fiddle - if not what is that you want